# c++ unknown type name in template

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, I have a very simple program but it can't be compiled.

**Darray.h**

```
#ifdef DARRAY_H
#define DARRAY_H
namespace myspace{
    template<class T>
    class DynamicTypeArray{
    public:
           DynamicTypeArray(); 
    private:
           int length;
    };
}
#endif
```

**Darray.cpp**

```
#include "Darray.h"
namespace myspace{
    template <class T>
    DynamicTypeArray<T>::DynamicTypeArray(){
         length = 0;
    }
}
```

I think it is pretty straightforward, but when I try to compile it with

> g++ Darray.cpp

it gives me an error

> unknown type name 'DynamicTypeArray'

Am I doing anything wrong here? The problem drives me crazy right now.

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Seems ok [here](https://ideone.com/QouFxu).

Comment: Sorry, it's #ifndef, not #ifdef, It's too hard to find them.

Answer (score 0):

C++ templates are built in a way that (afaik) you can't have template class split over header (.h) and implementation (.cpp) files.